# Delete records from Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I need to delete records from one table based on inner join condition on other two tables, however query runs for ages.

```
DELETE FROM public.blacklist WHERE subject_id NOT IN(
SELECT DISTINCT a.id FROM public.subject a
INNER JOIN stg.blacklist_init b ON a.subject_id=b.customer_code);
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`, and I think you don't need a `DISTINCT`

```
DELETE FROM public.blacklist bl
 WHERE NOT EXISTS  (
                     SELECT 0 
                       FROM public.subject a
                      INNER JOIN stg.blacklist_init b 
                         ON a.subject_id=b.customer_code
                      WHERE a.id = bl.subject_id 
                     );
```